# Auto Text field values from Database in yii

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I have a form with fields like pincode,village,district etc. auto fill these values when I enter `pincode`. Please provide a sample code for achieving this.
thanks in advance.

```
<tr>
<div class="row">
<td><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'pin'); ?></td>
<td><?php echo $form->textField($model,'pin',array('size'=>6,'maxlength'=>6,'style'=>'height:34px;')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'pin'); ?></td>
</div>
```

```
<tr>
<div class="row">
<td><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'street'); ?></td>
<td><?php echo $form->textField($model,'street',array('size'=>25,'maxlength'=>25,'style'=>'height:34px;')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'street'); ?></td>
</div>
```

```
<tr>
<div class="row">
<td><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'village'); ?></td>
<td><?php echo $form->textField($model,'village',array('size'=>25,'maxlength'=>25,'style'=>'height:34px;')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'village'); ?></td>
</div>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: are you storing the values of `pin` in your db ?

Comment: Do you load $model before render?

Comment: yeah, I have all data of pincodes in database. as well as villages and districts etc etc

Comment: probably duplicate i guess you want some autocomplete? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215869/autocomplete-in-yii2

Comment: no.. no, I already Tried that CJuiAutoComplete. for e.g If I enter 522002 it will automatically fill the other fields Guntur as District,GunturMandal as Mandal like that.

Comment: Do you mean that you want when the user enters the pincode then the street and village will populate automatically? If this is the case then you need a combination of autocomplete and ajax. Please, rephrase your question and try to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your table name is `areas`, and `Areas` is Model for that table.

Bellow i am repeating(not exactly) view code from your question and i am attaching `ajax` call on your `pincode` field and  `class` property on your other text fields.

```
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'pin'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'pin',array(
        'size'=>6,
        'maxlength'=>6,
        'style'=>'height:34px;',
        //Ajax call to get the pin related values, onBlur.
        'ajax' => array
                (
                'type' => 'POST',
                'dataType'=>'JSON',
                'url' => CController::createUrl('site/getValuesByPincode'),
                'success'=>'js:function(output){$(".setVillage").val(output.village); $(".setStreet").val(output.street);}'
                )

        )); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'pin'); ?>

    <br/><br/>

    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'street'); ?>
    <?php 
    //adding a class 
    echo form->textField($model,'street',array('size'=>25,'maxlength'=>25,'style'=>'height:34px;','class'=>'getStreet')); 
    ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'street'); ?>

    <br/><br/>

    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'village'); ?>
    <?php
    //Ading a class 
    echo $form->textField($model,'village',array('size'=>25,'maxlength'=>25,'style'=>'height:34px;','class'=>'getVillage'));
    ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'village'); ?>
```

And i am creating an action `getValuesByPincode` in my controller(ex: site controller) to serve my ajax call.

```
public function actionGetValuesByPincode()
{
    $pincode = $_POST['Areas']['pin'];
    $data = Areas::model()->find('pin=:pin', array(':pin' => $pincode));
    $output = array();
    if (count($data) > 0)
    {
        $output['village'] = $data->village;
        $output['street'] = $data->street;
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
}
```